# Having strange artifacts on adding EffectComposer to a room lit with Spot Light react-three-fibre and react-postprocessing

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

Hi I have make a 3D room with spotlights pointing upwards to the ceiling.
When EffectComposer tag is used, Then I am seeing wierd contour lines in the reflected lights.

[image]

Without the EffectComposer the lighting has a smooth gradient

[image]

I need to use Bloom to my scene but this is causing some issues.
I am using the effect like this
`<EffectComposer> <Bloom luminanceThreshold={0.2} luminanceSmoothing={2} height={500} /> </EffectComposer>`

Comment: Check out [this conversation](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/srgbencoding-with-post-processing/12582), it might give you the answer you're looking for. It might have something to do with the texture encoding.

Comment: @Marquizzo I tried setting renderer parameters according to the thread, but I am still seeing the above issue. I also tried to use other postprocessing libraries also apart from the react-postprocessing with the render setting but still no help